# Turn cookie to object

Tags: javascript

I have a cookie:

```
$.cookie("bla")
"eid:12345666c85f0beaad3c52947bb2dd88"
```

In the past I have used parse.JSON:

```
$.parseJSON($.cookie("bla"))
(program):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
```

How can I turn the cookie into an object?

Comment: $.parseJSON('{' + $.cookie("bla") + '}') ... gave the same error

Comment: parseJSON is failing because the string you have isn't remotely like JSON.

Comment: What sort of object do you want to create from it?

Comment: the content of your cookie is no serialized json so parseJSON fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string and creating the object from the split's result.

```
//get cookie as string
var cookie = $.cookie("bla");
//split string on ':'
var cookieArray = cookie.split(':');
//create object and set key to cookieArray[0] (left side of ':')
//and set value to cookieArray[1] (right side of ':')
var cookieJSON = {}
cookieJSON[cookieArray[0]] = cookieArray[1];
```

Comment: Thanks. Went with this answer only because my hand was held a bit going through it with the comments

Answer (score 0):

Need to save a valid json string as a cookie first. It's missing the surrounding braces, and string quotes.

```
var object = { "eid": "12345666c85f0beaad3c52947bb2dd88" };
$.cookie("blah", JSON.serialize(object));
$.parseJSON($.cookie("blah"))
```

Just assuming how your cookie set function works, no idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookieArr = ($.cookie("bla")).split(":");
var object = {}; 
object[cookieArr[0]] = cookieArr[1];
```